# How to parse specific variable of a dict in Ansible

Tags: json, dictionary, ansible

I have an Ansible job that run on 2 or more urls. Each url returns the same variables with different values (but have similar pattern). Here is the return data of the job:

```
"message": [
    {
      "url": "http://0.0.0.1:xxx1",
      "content": [
          {
            "message": "This is message number 1",
            "message2": "This is message2 number 1"
          },
          {
              "message": "This is message number 2",
              "message2": "This is message2 number 2"
          },
          {
              "message": "This is message number 3",
              "message2": "This is message2 number 3"
          }
        ]
    },
    {
        "url": "http://0.0.0.2:xxx2",
        "content": [
            {
              "message": "This is message number 1",
              "message2": "This is message2 number 1"
            },
            {
                "message": "This is message number 2",
                "message2": "This is message2 number 2"
            },
            {
                "message": "This is message number 3",
                "message2": "This is message2 number 3"
            }
          ]
      }
```

I want to parse the variable 'message' without changing the structure of the returned data. My expected result is like this:

```
"message": [
  {
    "url": "http://0.0.0.1:xxx1",
    "content": [
        {
          "message": "message number 1",
          "message2": "This is message2 number 1"
        },
        {
            "message": "message number 2",
            "message2": "This is message2 number 2"
        },
        {
            "message": "message number 3",
            "message2": "This is message2 number 3"
        }
      ]
  },
  {
      "url": "http://0.0.0.2:xxx2",
      "content": [
          {
            "message": "message number 1",
            "message2": "This is message2 number 1"
          },
          {
              "message": "message number 2",
              "message2": "This is message2 number 2"
          },
          {
              "message": "message number 3",
              "message2": "This is message2 number 3"
          }
        ]
    }
```

I know how to parse the data. My struggle is to keep the structure as is. How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the structure in Jinja

```yaml
    updates: |
      {% for i in message %}
      - content:
      {% for m in i.content %}
      {% set arr=m.message.split() %}
      {% set message={'message': arr[2:]|join(' ')} %}
        - {{ m|combine(message) }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% for k in i %}
      {% if k != 'content' %}
        {{ k }}: {{ i[k] }}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
```

gives

```yaml
  updates: |-
    - content:
      - {'message': 'message number 1', 'message2': 'This is message2 number 1'}
      - {'message': 'message number 2', 'message2': 'This is message2 number 2'}
      - {'message': 'message number 3', 'message2': 'This is message2 number 3'}
      url: http://0.0.0.1:xxx1
    - content:
      - {'message': 'message number 1', 'message2': 'This is message2 number 1'}
      - {'message': 'message number 2', 'message2': 'This is message2 number 2'}
      - {'message': 'message number 3', 'message2': 'This is message2 number 3'}
      url: http://0.0.0.2:xxx2
```

Convert the block to YAML

```yaml
    messag2: "{{ updates|from_yaml }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  messag2:
  - content:
    - message: message number 1
      message2: This is message2 number 1
    - message: message number 2
      message2: This is message2 number 2
    - message: message number 3
      message2: This is message2 number 3
    url: http://0.0.0.1:xxx1
  - content:
    - message: message number 1
      message2: This is message2 number 1
    - message: message number 2
      message2: This is message2 number 2
    - message: message number 3
      message2: This is message2 number 3
    url: http://0.0.0.2:xxx2
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:
    message:
      - content:
        - message: This is message number 1
          message2: This is message2 number 1
        - message: This is message number 2
          message2: This is message2 number 2
        - message: This is message number 3
          message2: This is message2 number 3
        url: http://0.0.0.1:xxx1
      - content:
        - message: This is message number 1
          message2: This is message2 number 1
        - message: This is message number 2
          message2: This is message2 number 2
        - message: This is message number 3
          message2: This is message2 number 3
        url: http://0.0.0.2:xxx2

    updates: |
      {% for i in message %}
      - content:
      {% for m in i.content %}
      {% set arr=m.message.split() %}
      {% set message={'message': arr[2:]|join(' ')} %}
        - {{ m|combine(message) }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% for k in i %}
      {% if k != 'content' %}
        {{ k }}: {{ i[k] }}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    messag2: "{{ updates|from_yaml }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: updates
    - debug:
        var: messag2
```

---

Q: ***"This solution works in vars. Using it in tasks, since my data is from json output, set_fact gives me an offending line in the result."***

A: There is no reason for moving the *updates* and *messag2* variables into the *set_fact* task.

a) The play below works fine also when *message* comes from a task

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    updates: |
      {% for i in message %}
      - content:
      {% for m in i.content %}
      {% set arr=m.message.split() %}
      {% set message={'message': arr[2:]|join(' ')} %}
        - {{ m|combine(message) }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% for k in i %}
      {% if k != 'content' %}
        {{ k }}: {{ i[k] }}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    messag2: "{{ updates|from_yaml }}"

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: message.yml
    - debug:
        var: updates
    - debug:
        var: messag2
```

b) You can put the declarations of *updates* and *messag2* into the *set_fact* tasks. The play below works fine

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: message.yml
    - set_fact:
        updates: |
          {% for i in message %}
          - content:
          {% for m in i.content %}
          {% set arr=m.message.split() %}
          {% set message={'message': arr[2:]|join(' ')} %}
            - {{ m|combine(message) }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% for k in i %}
          {% if k != 'content' %}
            {{ k }}: {{ i[k] }}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
    - set_fact:
        messag2: "{{ updates|from_yaml }}"

    - debug:
        var: updates
    - debug:
        var: messag2
```

c) You can't put both declarations of *updates* and *messag2* into single *set_fact* task because *messag2* knows nothing about *updates* this way. The play below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - include_vars:
        file: message.yml
    - set_fact:
        updates: |
          {% for i in message %}
          - content:
          {% for m in i.content %}
          {% set arr=m.message.split() %}
          {% set message={'message': arr[2:]|join(' ')} %}
            - {{ m|combine(message) }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% for k in i %}
          {% if k != 'content' %}
            {{ k }}: {{ i[k] }}
          {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
        messag2: "{{ updates|from_yaml }}"

    - debug:
        var: updates
    - debug:
        var: messag2
```

failes

> ... The error was: 'updates' is undefined ...

Comment: Put the declarations into separate *set_fact* tasks. I added examples.